# Enviar comando ssh mediante php con boton submit

Tags: php

Mi problema es el siguiente tengo un formulario el cual envia mediante el comando ssh2 de php5, el restart o reiniciar a un mikrotik mediante ssh, lo que quiero es que dicho boton solo se deje precionar 1 vez cada 10 segundos y que cuando lo preciono como que me vuelve a cargar la pagina, pero no me esta funcionando

este es el codigo

del index.php

Reiniciar internet

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#reiniciar1').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var el = $(this);
            el.prop('disabled', true);
            setTimeout(function(){el.prop('disabled', false); }, 3000);

        });
    });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
        $(".content").fadeOut(1500);
        },3000);
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
        var accion = $(this).attr('dir');
        $('form').attr('action', accion);
        $('form').submit();
    });

    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<?php if( isset( $_GET['msg'] ) && $_GET['msg'] == 1 ): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success content">
        <center><img src='img/smile.gif' border='0' align='absmiddle'>
        El Servicio a sido $ACTION espere 1 min antes de volverlo a     $ACTION.
        </center>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>

<div class="text-center" style="position: fixed; width: 100%;top: 7%;">
<form method="post" action="">

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="Reiniciar" value="Reiniciar" dir="release.php" id="reiniciar1" href="#" />

</form>
</div>
<div class="text-center" style="position: fixed; width: 100%;top: 27%;">
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="boton_1" value="Boton 1" dir="release.php" id="reiniciar1" href="#" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="boton_2" value="Boton 2" dir="release.php" id="reiniciar1" href="#" />

</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

este es el del release.php

```
include_once 'php/Components_Ssh.php';
include_once 'php/config.php';

$fecha = new DateTime();

$fp = fopen('php/log.txt', 'a');
fputs($fp, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . ' - ' . $fecha->format('d/m/Y H:i:s') . ' - reiniciar ' . '');
fclose($fp);

$ssh = new Components_Ssh($conf['host'], $conf['user'], $conf['pass'], $conf['puerto']);

$ssh->cmd("ip dhcp-client release 10");

$ssh->disconnect();

header("Location: /test/index.php?msg=1");
die();
```

Comment: ¿Te ha servido la respuesta? ¿Necesitas más datos?

Answer (score 2):

En este caso creo que tu problema es que estas refrescando la página. Entonces el contador se "reinicia" cada vez que la página se refresca.

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es añadir un `ajax` de manera que la página no se recargue y por tanto en contador no comience de cero.

Acuérdate también de la respuesta (cabeceras) en PHP. Te pongo un ejemplo del ajax:

```
$('#reiniciar1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this);
    el.prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function(){el.prop('disabled', false); }, 3000);
    $.ajax({
        type:  'GET',
        url:   'release.php'
    }).done(function() {
        alert('todo ha salido bien')
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('algo ha fallado')
    });
});
```